# Execute different component's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a header. Whenever the link `Portfolio` inside of the header is clicked, the route changes - I want to additionally trigger a different component's (`CardHolder`) function. How can I do so?

The components aren't connected yet whatsoever.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
                <Header/>
                ...
                <CartHolder />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

```
const header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Header container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">

                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Portfolio</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="ml-4">
                            About
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

BTW `CartHolder` is a class based component.

Comment: You have a router, yet I don't see any defined routes. Is the `CartHolder` a part of a specific route? Remeber that the router only renders components from current route, so if both header and cartholder are inside one route and `Portfolio` links to a different one, then both will get unmounted.

Comment: @DavidGildour Both CartHolder and Header are supposed to be displayed no matter what route, hence I spared the router elements from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `pathname` changes inside `CartHolder` using `useEffect` and `useLocation`, check the `pathname` and invoke the function if it's the portfolio route

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const CartHolder = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  const fn = () => {
    console.log('portfolio')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/') {
      fn()
    }
  }, [pathname])

  return ...
}
```

for class based components you will need to wrap the component with `withRouter` HOC that injects the props from `react-router-dom`

then in `componentDidUpdate` check if the route is the portfolio route but also check if the previous route is not the same as portfolio because componentDidUpdate will fire on every re-render

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class CartHolder extends Component {
  fn = () => {
    console.log('portfolio')
  }

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    const prevPathname = prevProps.location.pathname;
    const { pathname } = this.props.location;

    if (pathname === "/" && pathname !== prevPathname) {
      this.fn()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm new to react - what would be the equivalent for a class based component?

Comment: @Tim Updated my answer, let me know it works for you